# Spring Multi Path Variabe In Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a problem: 
This URL: `http://localhost:8080/SpringWebMVC/A1;A2;A3`

We can add more `A4, A4, A...n`. I don't know how to define /{pathvariable} in Spring so get list of path variable value.

Comment: Use http://localhost:8080/SpringWebMVC?p=A1&p=A2&p=A3&p=An You can bind this to a @RequestParam called p of type List

Comment: Your method is right, but the url has define "http://localhost:8080/SpringWebMVC/A1;A2;A3" and I must to find a solution in spring so get list of data from url.

Answer (score 0):

you can see Matrix Variables , may be they can be useful.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables

Answer (score 0):

I must to encode A1;A2;A3,...;An. Because, the symbol ";" is special in url. This is solution I refer by my master.